# WordPress front-page template navigation block corrupted: how to reset it?

Tags: wordpress, templates, layout, navigation, frontpage

In the main site of an old multisite WordPress install, looks like the navigation block is somewhat corrupted: it appears as a the mobile modal opened, and it pushes all the layout to the left.

On Chrome, Firefox and Safari this shows only for a few seconds, so it is impossible to use the browsers inspector. I noticed the problem using Google Pagespeed, where the homepage screenshot shows a defaced layout.

As the problem appeared on the homepage only, I tried making a new page, that was working perfectly, but as I have assigned it as frontpage the problem reappeared.

I have searched the web, nobody seems to experience a similar error. Of course I have tried flushing caches, deactivating plugins and switching to other themes, with no result, the problem disappeared only when I have cloned the main site: the clone has a perfect layout.

At this point I deduced that there must be some error in the navigation block of the front-page template of the main website - the install dates well back before the block editor - but how to correct it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In have found out that the problem was in a cache: naively, I thought that "Purge all" Litespeed command was a literal one, and turned out it is not.
I was lucky enough to reproduce the error long enough to use the inspector and found traces of a Litespeed file, so I went more carefully into its options and found that **Purge all purges "the caches entries created by this plugin except for Critical CSS & Unique CSS & LQIP caches".**
So I cleaned all caches one by one manually, and the problem was solved.

So to paraphrase the quote attributed to Rutherford, it was impossible until I understood it, and then it became trivial.